Adding a calculated column (defined by a large DAX code) to a Power BI dataflow
I have created several PBI dataflows, with the intention of them to feed a PBI datamart.  I want to create some calculated fields in the flow using DAX, but don't see an option for creating calculated fields using DAX. The only option I see is Power Query M code.  But if I have a calculated field that I can create using 50 lines of DAX code, am I supposed to write this in power query M code?

pls proivde some sample data and expected output.

Yes, in Power BI Dataflows, you cannot use DAX. Dataflows use Power Query M for all transformations and calculated fields.
Because,

Dataflows are designed to handle ETL process using Power Query before the data is sent to Power BI.
And DAX is used inside Power BI datasets, reports, and Data marts to create calculated columns or measures after the data has been loaded. DAX is not used in dataflows because it is used to perform calculations in a reporting context when dataset has been loaded, not during data transformation (ETL) which usually happens before loading the data to power bi


Good explanation.  I'm new to PBI datamarts.   If I understand you correctly, are you saying that once I create the datamart (which is fed from the dataflows) I can define calculated columns and measures using DAX inside the mart, just like I do with datasets and reports?

Yes, you got it. Once data has been loaded into PBI  (direct/import)either way, then you can easily create measures and calculated columns.
